Derivation of Linear Stability Analysis for Iterated Maps
I found the following derivation for linear stability analysis for iterated maps (https://people.uleth.ca/~roussel/nld/stability_maps.pdf)

Suppose that we are studying a map
$$ x_{n+1}=f\left(x_n\right) . $$
A fixed point is a point for which
$x_{n+1}=x_n=x^*=f\left(x^*\right)$, i.e. a fixed point is an
equilibrium point of a map.
As with differential equations, the study of the stability of fixed
points of maps generally proceeds by considering a small displacement
from the fixed point. Accordingly, let $\delta x_n=x_n-x^*$. Then,
taking a Taylor expansion of the map around $x^*$, we get
$$ x^*+\delta x_{n+1}=f\left(x^*+\delta
> x_n\right)=f\left(x^*\right)+f^{\prime}\left(x^*\right) \delta
> x_n+\ldots, $$
where $f^{\prime}=d f / d x$. Since $x^*=f\left(x^*\right)$, this
simplifies to
$$ \delta x_{n+1}=f^{\prime}\left(x^*\right) \delta x_n+\ldots $$
For sufficicently small $\delta x_n$, we can truncate the Taylor
expansion at this term.

Now what I don't get is the following identity
$$ 
x^*+\delta x_{n+1}=f\left(x^*+\delta x_n\right)
$$
With $x_n = x^* + \delta x_n$, we have
$$
x_{n+1} = f(x_n) = f(x^* + \delta x_n)
$$
But why can we say
$$
x_{n+1} = x^* + \delta x_{n+1}
$$
